# What are the best sources for fundamental financial data? (not yahoo or google, neiter SEC counts as good)

Tags: data, fundamentals, financial

I'm looking for a source for fundamental financial data, where I can download financial statements into excel. The source should provide the exact figures shown in the annual reports (not standardized) and it should be free.

To clarify I'm not looking for the standard SEC answer (I want both US and european companies) and neither am I looking for yahoo finance or google finance... I'm looking for Bloomberg/ Factset quality data.